# CSS Bottom Property doesn't work with percentages (only pixels)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a navigation bar for a website. I want to move a div up to be in the middle (height wise) of `#header`. I want to do this with percentages `(e.g bottom:50%)`. But it only works with pixels `(e.g bottom:200px)`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
}

#logo {
  background: red;
}

#logo img {
  background-color: coral;
}

#logo h2 {
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
}

#nav nav {
  position: relative;
  left: 85%;
  bottom: 50%;
  margin: 1em;
}

#nav nav a {
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', 'Rubik Mono One', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="" alt="" width="42" height="42">
    <h2>title</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
    <nav>
      <a routerLink="/"> HOME </a>
      <a routerLink="/about"> ABOUT </a>
      <a routerLink="/blog"> BLOG </a>
    </nav>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: the duplicate deals with `top` and the same happen for `bottom`: parent element need to have a height defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code:

```css
html, body { 
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
    position: relative;
    height: 10%;
}
#header h2{
  margin: 0;
}
#logo {
    background:red; 
}
#logo img{
    background-color: coral;    
}
#logo h2{
    font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive; 
}

#nav nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 85%;
    bottom: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
}
#nav nav a {
    font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah','Rubik Mono One', sans-serif;
    margin-right: 1em; 
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id = "header">
  <div id = "logo">
    <img src="" alt="" width="42" height="42">
    <h2>title</h2>
  </div>
  <div id = "nav">
      <nav> 
          <a routerLink="/"> HOME </a>
          <a routerLink="/about"> ABOUT </a>
          <a routerLink="/blog"> BLOG </a>
      </nav>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: I'm confused about why this works. when you set #nav nav position: absolute, doesn't that make the parent 'html'? Therefore when you type bottom 50% the #nav #nav should appear in the middle of the document (height wise) shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

`position: relative;` property does not work on %; if you try with `position: absolute;` then it will work.
I donot know what you are actually trying to do, but according to your question this can we solution.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
}

#logo {
  background: red;
}

#logo img {
  background-color: coral;
}

#logo h2 {
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
}

#nav nav {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#000;
  left: 0%;
  bottom: 50%;
  color:#fff;
}

#nav nav a {
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', 'Rubik Mono One', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="" alt="" width="42" height="42">
    <h2>title</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
    <nav>
      <a routerLink="/"> HOME </a>
      <a routerLink="/about"> ABOUT </a>
      <a routerLink="/blog"> BLOG </a>
    </nav>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`div#logo` blocks the entire width of the page. So the navigation menu comes in the next line.

you can either make `#logo` and `#nav`  as `display:inline-block` with `width: 300px; and width: calc(100vw - 300px)`

Or you can refer existing templates like in bootstrap.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
  </div>
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp